# Excel: Using formula on Referenced cell from another sheet

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2016

What I am trying to do is to reference proper cell reference from another worksheet in the same WB.

That is not a big deal using `'='3) MA_Calculation'!C2` as a simplest. Problem which I have is the output of some cells where I have values only in one row, where other row is empty, which is fine, but as you can see in A and B columns data with positions, that is exactly where I need help. In a case I have upper position only it will show me in upper part or row 2, BUT I need to have it on a down position or row 3,leaving upper position empty in that case. And in both matches should be as in this example.

To better understand this issue I will just give you an example where or what it should be, consider you got some kind of reactor and you wanna put some "mixture" inside but the order of them is defined, X mixture goes first (bottom) then Y goes second (upper) and so on. And sometimes you got only one mixture which has to be on bottom only.

Because I have different instances I need to have formula which will recognize that and put it always on down (bottom) position when it is alone.

[image: excel]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `='3) MA_Calculation'!C3` to `=IF('3) MA_Calculation'!C3="",'3) MA_Calculation'!C2,'3) MA_Calculation'!C3)`

Then   `='3) MA_Calculation'!C2` to `=IF(OR('3) MA_Calculation'!C3 = "",'3) MA_Calculation'!C2 = ""),"",'3) MA_Calculation'!C2)`

and drag rightwards.. That should do.